# Move customer to other group when buying a product

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-group

Can you move a customer to a group after checkout if (s)he buys a specific product? (We will sell membership cards trough our magento store. When they buy a card, they should become part of the member group That i've created).

edit: i'm using Magento 2.1.7

Comment: Please specify Magento version in your question.

Comment: It's version 2.1.7